# spacy - how to load a downloaded pretrained pipeline

Tags: python, spacy-3

How to load the downloaded pretrained pipeline and where is it explained in the document?

```
import spacy
spacy.cli.download("en_core_web_sm", False, False, "--target", "/tmp/spacy")
nlp = spacy.load("/tmp/spacy/en_core_web_sm")
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 1
----> 1 nlp = spacy.load("/tmp/spacy/en_core_web_sm")

File ~/venv/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py:54, in load(name, vocab, disable, enable, exclude, config)
     30 def load(
     31     name: Union[str, Path],
     32     *,
   (...)
     37     config: Union[Dict[str, Any], Config] = util.SimpleFrozenDict(),
     38 ) -> Language:
     39     """Load a spaCy model from an installed package or a local path.
     40 
     41     name (str): Package name or model path.
   (...)
     52     RETURNS (Language): The loaded nlp object.
     53     """
---> 54     return util.load_model(
     55         name,
     56         vocab=vocab,
     57         disable=disable,
     58         enable=enable,
     59         exclude=exclude,
     60         config=config,
     61     )

File ~/venv/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy/util.py:434, in load_model(name, vocab, disable, enable, exclude, config)
    432         return load_model_from_package(name, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    433     if Path(name).exists():  # path to model data directory
--> 434         return load_model_from_path(Path(name), **kwargs)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    435 elif hasattr(name, "exists"):  # Path or Path-like to model data
    436     return load_model_from_path(name, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[arg-type]

File ~/venv/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy/util.py:505, in load_model_from_path(model_path, meta, vocab, disable, enable, exclude, config)
    503 config_path = model_path / "config.cfg"
    504 overrides = dict_to_dot(config)
--> 505 config = load_config(config_path, overrides=overrides)
    506 nlp = load_model_from_config(
    507     config,
    508     vocab=vocab,
   (...)
    512     meta=meta,
    513 )
    514 return nlp.from_disk(model_path, exclude=exclude, overrides=overrides)

File ~/venv/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy/util.py:681, in load_config(path, overrides, interpolate)
    679 else:
    680     if not config_path or not config_path.is_file():
--> 681         raise IOError(Errors.E053.format(path=config_path, name="config file"))
    682     return config.from_disk(
    683         config_path, overrides=overrides, interpolate=interpolate
    684     )

OSError: [E053] Could not read config file from /tmp/spacy/en_core_web_sm/config.cfg
```

Below worked but it depends on the version, hence should not be the correct way.

```
nlp = spacy.load("/tmp/spacy/en_core_web_sm/en_core_web_sm-3.5.0/")
```

##### Environmnet

```
python 3.9.13
spacy 3.5.0
```